# Changing the Header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I want my header to look like this:

[image]

How can I attach a short section title to a section? Is there a way to only display the title or the number of a section?

My header code so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

%Packages
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Header
\usepackage[headsepline=0.75pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont\itshape\color{gray}}
\clearpairofpagestyles              
\automark[section]{section}         
\ihead{\headmark - \pagemark}   

\begin{document}

\section{Formatvorlage: “Überschrift 1” Überschrift des Hauptberichtes Überschrift des Hauptberichtes (Kapitelnummer anpassen = Arbeitspunktnummer!)}\label{chap:Zusammenfassung}
\sectionmark{short titel}
\addsecmark{short titel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please complete your code that it's compilable (but still as short as possible). It'll make things easier for the people willing to help and test.

Comment: @Miyase is this better now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Now people can test and modify your code to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. It breaks several features of these classes.

Remark: I do not know, if there are unnumbered sections and what the header should show for such unnumbered sections and for eg. the ToC.

Suggestion:

```latex
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Header
\usepackage[headsepline=0.75pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftfirstmark}
\ohead*{\rightmark\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\Ifnumbered{section}{\MakeMarkcase{\sectionmarkformat}}{}}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection\ - }
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\itshape\color{gray}}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}

\doforeachtocfile{\AfterTOCHead[#1]{\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{\csname listof#1name\endcsname}}{}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\minisec{Text zum Füllen der Seite}
\Blindtext
\section[head={short titel}]{Formatvorlage: “Überschrift 1” Überschrift des Hauptberichtes Überschrift des Hauptberichtes (Kapitelnummer anpassen = Arbeitspunktnummer!)}\label{chap:Zusammenfassung}
\blindtext
\section[head=test]{Weitere Überschrift}
\Blindtext[6]
\addsec[head=Kurzform nicht nummerierte Überschrift]{Ausführliche Version der nicht nummerierten Überschrift}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**: As mentioned in a comment, there will be no unnumbered sections in the document.

Example without unnumbered sections:

```latex
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Header
\usepackage[headsepline=0.75pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftfirstmark}
\ohead*{\rightmark\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\Ifnumbered{section}{\MakeMarkcase{\sectionmarkformat}}{}}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection\ - }
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\itshape\color{gray}}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}

\doforeachtocfile{\AfterTOCHead[#1]{\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{\csname listof#1name\endcsname}}{}}}

\begin{document}
\section[head={short titel}]{Formatvorlage: “Überschrift 1” Überschrift des Hauptberichtes Überschrift des Hauptberichtes (Kapitelnummer anpassen = Arbeitspunktnummer!)}\label{chap:Zusammenfassung}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thats kind of what I was looking for. Except that the short titel is supposed to be on every page. Also my hyphen is missing :/

Comment: Which hyphen is missing? What should happen if there are unnumbered sections like table of contents? Or do have no unnumbered sections? In my example the short title is in header of every page.

Comment: The hyphen between the Section number an the page is gone. In this case the whole article is one section. so every page should have the same short title and section number.

Comment: Did you use my code? Including the redefinition of \sectionmarkformat? It inserts the hyphen, if the section is numbered.  As you can see in the screenshots, there is a hyphen between the section number and the page number for numbered sections.
I have added an example without unnumbered sections.